# Applying a formula to an entire table in R

Tags: r

Hello everyone I am back with another issue concerning R. So the problem goes like this, There is a table containing performance of players in a football match with various parameters like number of fouls committed, goals ,..etc measured about each player.

I would like to apply a formula to measure the rating of player:

```
Player_rating=(goals scored + 0.5 * Assist + 0.5 * Shots on goal 
              - 0.2 * fouls commited -   0.8 * red card - 0.4 * yellow card 
              + 0.2 * saves)
```

The output needs to appear as a new column in the table containing the data, Assume table is called as player_details

Before:

```
  Name  Goals Yellow.card
  A      1       0
  B      0       2
  C      2       1
```

After:

```
 Name  Goals Yellow.card Player_rating
  A      1       0            15
  B      0       2            5
  C      2       1            26
```

Thank you

Comment: You have in your formula fields like "Assists", "Shots on Goal"m etc. Where are these fields in your example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Table I understand its a dataframe. Here I have created a dummy data frame with the fields you mentioned.

```
df <- data.frame(goals = 4:10, assist = 5:11, shots = 1:7, fouls = 7:1, red = sample(1:3, 7,replace=T), yellow = sample(3:7, 7,replace=T), saves = sample(1:10, 7,replace=T))

m <- df*c(1,0.5,0.5,-0.2, -0.8, -0.4,0.2)
df <- cbind(df, player_rating = rowSums(m))
```

I have taken an intermediate object **m**, you can omit it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

1. Create a function that takes a data frame and calculates the rating
2. Call the function and assign the result to a column

For example:

```
players <- data.frame(
  Name=c('A', 'B', 'C'),
  Goals=c(1, 0, 2),
  Yellow.card=c(0, 2, 1))

player_rating <- function(x) {
  x$Goals - 0.4 * x$Yellow.card
}
players$Rating <- player_rating(players)
players
```

Outputs:

```
  Name Goals Yellow.card Rating
1    A     1           0    1.0
2    B     0           2   -0.8
3    C     2           1    1.6
```

Comment: Could you modify this to work on a existing table with many rows and column?

Comment: I don't see what more you need. Just edit inside the function, like I did with `x$Goals` and `x$Yellow.card`.